# Most efficient way to edit the first line of a large input stream one manner, and all other lines a different manner?

Tags: python, processing-efficiency

The issue... (N=2*10^7)

Going from this:

```
colName1 colName2 colName3 ... colNameN
1        x        x        ... x 
2        x        x        ... x
1        y        x        ... x
2        y        x        ... x  
...      ...      ...      ... ...
1        xx       xx       ... xx
2        xx       xx       ... xx
```

to this:

```
Sample colName1 colName2 colName3 ... colNameN
A       1        x        x       ... x 
A       2        x        x       ... x
B       1        y        x       ... x
B       2        y        x       ... x  
...     ...      ...      ...     ... ...
N       1        xx       xx      ... xx
N       2        xx       xx      ... xx
```

The problem:
I need to add "Sample" to the first "header" line, and the respective sample name to every other line there after. The sample name will be stored in an object.

Confounding issues:

- The data is coming from an input stream; currently handled via subprocess.PIPE
- It will be common for the files to have 20 million lines, so checking a firstLine flag every time would be costly?

I'm wondering if there is a way to just do something to just the first line of input in the input stream.

Or...

Would it be easier just try all the lines the same, meaning we add the sample name to the header line. Then after, we edit the first word in the file from the sample name to "Sample\t"

How costly is this approach?
Currently, I have a firstLine flag, as seen below.

```
fileSTREAM = subprocess.Popen(callString, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

# To indicate the first line of the steam, which happens to be the column-headers.
firstLine = True

# Foreach to add a word to the front of each line of input.
for line in fileSTREAM.stdout:

    # Decode the input from btye literals to strings.
    currLine = line.decode("utf-8")

    # First line is different, we want to add SAMPLE, instead of the actual sample name.
    if firstLine == True:
        outputTARGET.write("SAMPLE \t%s" % currLine)
        firstLine = False

    # All other lines we want to add the sample name, instead of the word SAMPLE.
    else:
        outputTARGET.write(str(wildcards.samples) + "\t%s" % currLine)
```

Might not be a python specific problem, but I am looking for a python specific solution.

Comment: Why not simply read the first line from fileSTREAM, process it (include "Sample") and *then* go into your loop (**for line in fileSTREAM.stdout)?

Comment: Also note that **if firstLine == True** is redundant; merely **if firstLine** will do.

Comment: If I read just the first line,what function to you recommend to read up to the first "\n" character. 

readline()?

EDIT 2: Re-writing it else where to test. I get what you mean.
EDIT 3: Gotta run to class for a final, will close topic tonight!

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big shout out to @Prune, thank you :)

The best approach was to read the first line of the input stream. Python has great built-in functions to deal with this.

Ended up going with this:

```
# Call the function and capture its output to modify each line.
fileSTREAM = subprocess.Popen(callString, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

# Initially read and edit just the first, adding 'SAMPLE' to header line.
outputTARGET.write("SAMPLE \t%s" % fileSTREAM.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8"))

# Add the sampleName to each line after the header line.
for line in fileSTREAM.stdout:
    # Decode the input from btye literals to strings
    outputTARGET.write(str(wildcards.samples) + "\t%s" % line.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Still learning StackOverflow. A follow up question... what's the best way to close this topic? I took Prune's advice and then updated my code. I've posted the resultant code that I am happy with. Do I just select this as the answer tomorrow?